# SODA querying for JODA DateTime in DB4O

Tags: java, jodatime, db4o

I'am using db4o and JODA and got an issue with storing/recieving DateTime objects.
At least I think that's were the problem is.

My datamodell looks pretty much like this:

```
DataFile.class
    enum FileType {...}
    further attributes... (primitve data types)

Product.class extends DataFile.class
    enum ProductType {...}
    further attributes... (primitve data types)

KindOfProduct.class extends Product.class
    DateTime time
    further attributes... (primitve data types)
```

I'am creating KindOfProduct objects and store them in an EmbeddedDatabase. 
For querying these objects I'am using SODA and got an DateTimeComparison.class which
implements Evaluation. Querying for fields other than DateTime works fine, but a DateTime
query fails. The strange thing is, that the evaluate method gets called just one time, regardless of how many objects are stored in my database. The include method of [candidate](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/api/com/db4o/query/Candidate.html) gets called with
true, but the candidate is not included in the ObjectSet. So it seems like an error occurs somewhere
and db4o exits without throwing an exception (which is a known issue for evaluating SODA querys,
by the looks of it).
Querying with the Object Manager Enterprise plugin for Eclipse fails to. I'am getting an
"Cannot display results" error message.

I'm pretty sure, that I've implemented the [Evaluation](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.0/java/api/com/db4o/query/Evaluation.html) interface correctly (I've done similar for
a different data type than DateTime and it works fine). I dont think, that I need to implement a
TypeHandler for storing DateTime objects, since there was no need to do so in an other project
of mine (I was using native querys in that case, but I think thats not the point).

So, any ideas on how to look for? Any known pitfalls?

EDIT: code of my evaluation class

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

import com.db4o.query.Candidate;
import com.db4o.query.Evaluation;

public class DateTimeComparison implements Evaluation {

protected enum Operator {

    GREATER, SMALLER, EQUAL

}

private Operator operator = null;
private DateTime value = null;

public DateTimeComparison(String operator, DateTime value) {

    if (operator.equals(">")) {
        this.operator = Operator.GREATER;
    } else {
        if (operator.equals("<")) {
            this.operator = Operator.SMALLER;
        } else {
            this.operator = Operator.EQUAL;
        }
    }
    this.value = value;

}

public void evaluate(Candidate candidate) {

    DateTime dateTime = (DateTime) candidate.getObject();

    boolean match = false;
    switch (operator) {
    case GREATER:
        match = dateTime.compareTo(value) > 0;
        break;
    case SMALLER:
        match = dateTime.compareTo(value) < 0;
        break;
    case EQUAL:
        match = dateTime.compareTo(value) == 0;
        break;
    }
    candidate.include(match);
    System.out.println(match);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your evaluation code / class?

Otherwise:

Note that evaluations will be 'slow', because the cannot use indexes. On large data sets this becomes an issue.

The most reliable, yet ugly way to avoid issues it store a regular Java Date in the stored object. And the translate the Date field to a JodaTime DateTime in the getters/setters. And in for the query as well.

To the typehandler: In theory you can make it work. A simple type handler which just stores the DateTime is probably not that hard. But for advanced features, like indexes typehandlers are a nightmare (no doc, need to cast stuff to internal datastructures etc).

Comment: I've added some code. The strange thing is, that the println gets reached, so I think there's nothing wrong with my implementation. I've also tryed to add a type handler, which stores DateTime as a long, but that didn't help...

Comment: Hmm, looks fine. Can you post a small working example? To me that looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to build a test case, I've found my error.
The problem wasn't the evaluation, but the way how I was building my constraints for the query. I am working on a way to build those constraints dynamicly, by reading them from a txt file. I didn't though of the fact that I need to pay attention in which order the constraints are linked. For example: (A and B) or C doesn't equals A and (B or C). So I ended up with a constraint that didn't representet the query I wanted to build.

I am now defining my constrains and then declare how they are should be linked, using Reverse Polish Notation, so I don't need to care about brackets. This seems to work pretty nice...